# Set VLC to stay in Playlist Mode when Video Comes Up

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a mixed playlist of videos / songs. When its playing a song and the next one is a video, VLC switches to video mode.

I would rather like it to stay in playlist mode and show the video in the bottom left corner like it does when i click the playlist button on video mode.

How can I set VLC to remain in playlist mode when a video starts playing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to preferences and Select the Video tab and uncheck "enable video" . Now you can listen to video songs without the video propping up.

Comment: Wow, that's a confusingly named option. I would expect unchecking something called "enable video" to disable all video related features. And not just to disable activating the video view in some circumstances. But indeed, that is exactly what it does. Clicking the button that toggles the playlist view still goes to the video view if you toggle away from the playlist view.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. When I start a video from the file manager, it shows the playlist (normal, I guess), but when I turn off the playlist, it just shows the VLC logo instead of the video. I have to then select the video track every time.

Comment: it just disables video, but I just want to disable hiding playlist/library when I double click a video from a playlist. So I still want to keep a video stream

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand the issue, since I was looking for the same thing.

Whenever you will start a new video, the playlist will "disappear", and you have to turn it ON again (CTRL+L/toggle button). It is annoying.

Go to **Preferences**, in the main **Interface** section, look for option group **Playlist and instances**.

I had check this 2 options:

- **Allow only one instance**
- **Enqueue items into playlist in one instance mode**

This seems to solve the problem a bit.

What are the results?
If I will play something, the playlist will not disappear anymore. However if I will go to fullscreen mode and go back to window mode, the playlist will vanish.

If I will stay in window mode, and go on to play whatever I want, it is ok, and stays OK. But once I will close VLC Player, and open it again, open something (video file), again, the playlist will vanish, but after I turn playlist ON again, it will stay. So results I get is:

- open playlist with videos songs etc.
- start to play (my playlist will hide)
- turn ON the playlist (so you can see it)
- and that is it; STAY IN THE WINDOW MODE

This steps I need to repeat each time I will close VLC Media Player.

It is a little bit less annoying, but still bit problematic.

Additional note:
Somewhere else I had read, that this issue is from 2012 (!)
and it will be fix with a new GUI of 4.0

When that will happen? Not sure...
I had test this with VLC Portable version 3.0.18

Hope this helps.